# powershell - unable to exclude file/folder names while searching for a string in all files under a directory

Tags: powershell

i wish to search for all url strings containing `http` and `tfs.mybank` under `D:\lm` folder while excluding folders `_backup` and `Informatica` and filenames containing `.csv` and `.log`

The purpose is to collect all repository urls that are used in our projects.

Below attempt get me the results in powershell but fails to exclude the mentioned folders like `_backup`

```
$uniqueUrls = @{}

Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\CCNet\lm\" -Recurse -Exclude "*.log*", "*.csv", "*.bak*"  | Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch '\\_backup\\|\\Informatica\\' } | Select-String -Pattern "tfs.mybank" | ForEach-Object {

    $url = $_.Line

    if($url -match "http"){

        $uniqueUrls[$url] = $true

    }  
}

$uniqueUrls.Keys | ForEach-Object{

    Write-Output $_

} >D:\alltfsforlm.txt
```

Results:

> server\projects.bak_SM_06_02_2021_backup\sm_deploy_dev.xml:
> http://deploydev:mybankMBC100@tfs.mybank.com:8080/tfs/Default/MHRS.SM/_git/SM.Portal
>
> server\projects_obsolete_and_backups\SM_hri\SmOrchestratorTasks_cso.xml:
> http://tfs.mybank.com:8080/tfs/default
>
> server\projects.current\Backup_MBCDeploymentScript_6_4_2014\CreatePackage.MBCServices.FN.xml:
> http://tfs.mybank.com:8080/tfs/default
>
> server\projects.bak_SM_06_02_2021_backup\sm_deploy_main.xml:
> http://tfs.mybank.com:8080/tfs

As you see `_backup` is populated in the results when it should not.

Can you please suggest?

Comment: Just add *_backup to the exclude list and remove the Where-Object

Comment: @MickeyCohen i tried the following ` -Exclude "*.log*", "*.csv", "*.bak*", "*backup", "*_backup", "*_backup*","*backup*"` but i still see `backup` in the outputs.

Comment: Try using wildcard. i.e *_backup like you initially did with the file extensions *.log *.csv etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
...| Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch '\\_backup\\|\\Informatica\\' } |...
```

From your unwanted output it seems that your _backup folders mostly have that label at the end of the folder name and not the start. The way you labeled the backup folders is also not very consistent (Backup_, _backup, _backups). Right now you are filtering out files with **\_backup\** and **\Informatica\** in the path.

Try matching just the word backup (Powershell is case-insentive).

```
 ...| Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch 'backup|\\Informatica\\' } |...
```

Comment: tried your suggestion ` Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch 'backup|\\Informatica\\' }` yet it is populating `backup` in the results like `server\projects.bak_SM_06_02_2021_backup\sm_deploy_dev.xml:
http://deploydev:mybankMBC100@tfs.mybank.com:8080/tfs/Default/MHRS.SM/_git/SM.Portal`

Comment: `"server\projects.bak_SM_06_02_2021_backup\sm_deploy_dev.xml" -match 'backup|\\Informatica\\'` results in True for me in Windows Powershell and powershell core. Mickey Cohen's comment should work too, so I think you have to look at the filenames then. Can't replicate you whole filesystem ;)